# Execute python program with bash script

Tags: python, bash, environment-variables

I have following bash script:

```
export MYCONFIG_CONFIG=TEST
/home/bmwant/projects/test/venv/bin/python3 /home/bmwant/projects/test/script.py
```

My python script needs environment variable which I have set, but running this script as

```
bash run_python.sh
```

shows an error

```
/home/bmwant/projects/test/venv/bin/python3: can't open file 'home/bmwant/projects/tes': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

What is wrong? I have set script as executable with `chmod u+x run_python.sh`

Comment: try putting the path to the python script in quotes and double check its correct

Comment: There is a missing `t` on the directory in the error?

Comment: Should `home/bmwant/projects/tes` be `home/bmwant/projects/test` (missing t)?

Comment: @moose no...look at his bash script again... the path he has is "/home/bmwant/projects/test/script.py" the interpreter isnt reading the full path for some reason...

Comment: strange but path is cropped for some reason

Comment: check again `run_python.sh`. that's strange.
you can also `shebang` it. (google _python3 shebang_)

Comment: What do you see if you write `bash -x run_python.sh` at the prompt?  You should probably [update the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30804890/edit) to include this output, as it's near impossible to put it in a comment (no code formatting facilities).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem was in file format. I have created it in Windows and then copy via FileZilla to remote server where I was trying to run it. So just run

```
apt-get install dos2unix
dos2unix run_python.sh
bash run_python.sh
```

and all will work well. Thanks @Horst for the hint.

Comment: Please accept this answer (or  delete the question) so that this no longer comes up as unresolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have made `script.py` executable?

```
chmod u+x /home/bmwant/projects/test/script.py
```

Try this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
export MYCONFIG_CONFIG=TEST
pushd /home/bmwant/projects/test/venv/bin/
./python3 /home/bmwant/projects/test/script.py
popd
```

You can run it via:

```
./run_python.sh
```

Comment: `-bash: ./run_python.sh: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

Comment: ah sorry ... do a `dos2unix run_python.sh` ... L̶i̶n̶u̶x̶ ̶c̶o̶l̶l̶i̶d̶e̶s̶ ̶w̶i̶t̶h̶ ̶m̶y̶ ̶w̶i̶n̶d̶o̶w̶s̶ ̶n̶e̶w̶l̶i̶n̶e̶s̶!̶ Bullshit, but it should help anyway ;)

Comment: You probably mean `./python3` not `.python3`.  With that fix, this might work if the symptom is caused by something which only allows a very short path name, but that would be highly ususual -- my guess is this won't help.  (Also, the `pushd` / `popd` is superfluous -- the script's working directory will be lost when the script finishes. You could just as well replace the `pushd` with a plain `cd`.)